# How do i hide this string if the value in the array is empty in javascript

Tags: javascript, hide

I have my array in an external js file. I wasnt to know how do i hide

```js
theString=theString+'<b>Random day of the week:</b> '+getRandomDayoftheweek(i)+'<br><br>';
```

if the record is empty

ive seen a bunch of answers on how to check if it is empty I want to hide the text "Random day of the week" all together

Answer (score 0):

Yea so I was able to figure it out. Now it seems kind of simple but here it is in case someone else has this question.

```js
if (getRandomDayoftheweek(i)!=="") {  
theString=theString+'<b>Random day of the week:</b> '+getRandomDayoftheweek(i)+'<br><br>';
}
```